# Amplify (JavaScript) - SAML login

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-amplify

I'm struggling for a few days now with AD SAML login in Amplify.

I've seen a few tutorials but my desired flow is different.
I don't have any button which will user click to trigger Auth sequence (and open popup).

Our users are going into a link:

```
https://....amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...
```

Which automatically redirect them into the front-end.

```
http://localhost:3000/#access_token=...&id_token=...&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=600
```

Which I can grab the `access_token`, `id_token`, `token_type` and `expires_in` from the query params.

I can do calls to our back-end with those tokens succesfully..

But what I am struggling with is make Amplify "login" sequence.. so it will identify the user and will create the localStorage values.. so for example when calling `Auth.currentSession()` it will return the token.

I've tried using `Auth.federatedSignIn(..)` but to no avail. I am not even sure if it's support this flow  or not.

This is what I tried:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn(
    'test-ad',
    {
        token: idToken,
        expires_at: expiresIn,
    },
    {
        name: "test-user",
    },
);
```

But I keep getting

> Unhandled Rejection (NotAuthorizedException): Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName

Which is strange as the `providerName` I'm passing ('test-ad') is the same as I configured in Cognito SAML `Provider Name` field (in Cognito -> User Pool -> Federation -> Identity Providers -> SAML -> new Provider)

I have my Amplify configured correctly

```
Amplify.configure({
   Auth: {
      identityPoolId: ...,
      region: ...,
      userPoolId: ...,
      userPoolWebClientId: ...
   }
});
```

And I can see the Chrome `network` call is with the correct payload:

```
{
   "IdentityPoolId":"us-east-x:...",
   "Logins":{
      "test-ad":"...idToken..."
   }
}
```

**so - How can I authenticate into Amplify using token? is it even possible?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, did you solve it?